# Bootstrap 4 with Django not displaying properly

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set-up Django to work with Bootstrap. I can't seem to get it to work properly, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. To start, I'm just displaying a panel. [It should look like this example from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_panels&stacked=h).

Instead, it looks like this: [image]

Here's what my generated HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Basic Panel</h2>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">A Basic Panel</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like some styling is being applied, since if I remove the stylesheet `<link>`, it seems to change the styling. On the Bootstrap site, it mentions that incomplete styling could be due to the `DOCTYPE` declaration, but as far as I can tell, I got that correct.

I assume I'm making some relatively obvious mistake here.

Comment: Yes, I have, and it works. But that does not explain why mine does not work. Furthermore, I want to use Bootstrap 4, not 3. I'll try messing with the integrity arg, but these are copied right off the Bootstrap site.

Comment: Doesn't work either, still looks the exact same. Deleted the crossorigin args as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your class. Now bootstrap change some classes. Look at this for more information https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#panels-thumbnails-and-wells

Comment: Awesome, totally missed this. Bootstrap would be wise to call a bit more attention to these changes on their website. Thanks!

Comment: Mauricio, I'm noticing that I actually don't get the same padding as the bootstrap examples [on this page](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/). [Here's an example](http://imgur.com/a/chb1Z). Is there an obvious thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I played around with your code and the w3schools example also. seems that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

does not play nicely. Is there a reason you want to not use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Because when I replaced that CSS link it worked fine in your code. Hope that was helpful.

Here is your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Basic Panel</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">A Basic Panel</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```